# Web browser support for the point unit

Tags: css

So I have this issue with responsive design. We're supposed to be realigning design for different screen sizes so that we present the best interface for each one.

The thing is that I can't figure out how to do this based on pixels. After all with media queries based on pixel, some of the newer phones look to be larger screens than my 40" tv does. So clearly this is wrong.

I wanted to use points to size things, since a point by definition is 1/72nd of an inch. So I should be able to make something 72pt and expect it to be an inch, this however does not seem hold true.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'em' rather than points or pixels. Set the `font-size: 62.5%;` on the body tag then for all other elements  1em = 10px, 1.2em = 12px.

Em's are relative unit so with the settings outlined above all elements should scale perfectly proportionally with the screen size. Just be careful with nested elements and generic rules as you can double up occasionally.

Dan Cederholm wrote an [excellent book featuring this technique](http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/)

Comment: ahh, but that doesn't tell me it's a 4" screen vs 40"

Comment: Thing is your assumption about 72dpi is incorrect, most windows ship with the screen set to 96 dpi. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fontblog/archive/2005/11/08/490490.aspx Most of the mobile/ipad sites I've built use this technique. Take a look at the discussion here http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10751/ems-percent-pixels-points/p1

Comment: Are you doing @media-screen and (max-width: 980px) {  } and so on to handle the screen size issue?

Comment: Yes.. also, while a screen might not be set to 72dpi, a pt is exactly 1⁄72.27 or an inch, or 0.3515 mm by definition, it's a unit of physical measure.

Comment: pt's were a unit of physical measure back in the letraset days, but their representation digitally doesn't match the real world value closely enough. Plus that's blown out of the water as soon as a user +'s the text size.